# Microservice architecture | Cannot assign requested address

Tags: java, apache, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

We have a microservice architecture where a single request from public (mobile app) internally results into 4 HTTP calls to different services.

One of the side affects of this I have observed is that, under heavy load, we start experiencing errors "Cannot assign requested address".

Running `netstat -tunp | wc -l` shows count of around 60k while normally it hovers around 3k.

It seems that I am running into port exhaustion. My application is written in Java using Apache HTTP Client.

What is the best way to solve this? I have few solutions in mind, but I am not sure if its the right way to go:

- Using keep alive
- Using Apache HTTP Pool (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html)

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the state of the sockets in `netstat` output? Are they in TIME_WAIT state? 

If so, another approach can be to configure Linux kernel settings. Take a look at those: [tcp_tw_reuse](https://ihazem.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/reducing-time_wait-socket-connections-recyclereuse), tcp_max_tw_buckets.

But, of course, the best way is to use connection pool with keep alive (when needed) connections. This will give you control of all aspects how connections are managed.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons you could be exhausting your available ports. (To avoid confusion, I'll call your user-facing server the "application".):

1. If you only have one application instance with one IP address, the maximum number of connections from that one machine to any of your four microservices is limited to the number of ephemeral ports. The default ephemeral port range varies by OS, but can be set to as high as 65535 (all ports available as emphemeral ports, though that would be highly unusual).
2. If your microservices' responses are sending `Connection: close`, or if your application doesn't support keep-alives, the application will close the TCP connection after each request. When a TCP connection is closed, the closing side goes into TIME_WAIT for 2xMSL (see [RFC 1122 section 4.2.2.13](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-87)). The default MSL again varies by OS, but a frequent default value is 30s. That means that the application will not be able use that port to communicate with the same microservice for 60s.
3. If instead the microservices are closing the connection (perhaps because the application is sending `Connection: close`), they will go into TIME_WAIT, and you may end up with port exhaustion on the microservice side.

The solution to port exhaustion depends on which of the above is happening. Here's what I would try:

- Enable keep-alives between your application and your microservices, and use a connection pool. This will greatly reduce the number of opened and closed connections between your application and the microservices, avoiding port exhaustion due to TIME_WAIT.
- 65k+ concurrent connections between a single application instance and a single microservice is a lot. If you are hitting this limit, you may need to increase the number of IP addresses your single application instance can use to make requests, perhaps by adding virtual IP addresses. You could also add application instances and put them behind a load balancer.
- You could increase the number of IP addresses your microservice is available at, and use a system like DNS round-robining to balance the load between the IP addresses.
- You could adjust the MSL at the OS level for your application and/or microservices to reduce the number of sockets in TIME_WAIT. I wouldn't recommend this, though; there are potentially negative side-effects, and in almost every case, your application or the architecture is wrong if this is the only solution to your problem.

I'd recommend starting with keep-alives and a connection pool first.